# Upgrade from symfony 1.0.11 to symfony 1.0.22

Tags: symfony1

I want to update symfony 1.0.11 to symfony 1.0.22. I am using php 5.1.6. Do I need to do any upgrades in my symfony code level as well? Or just upgrading the symfony library will do the trick for me?

Comment: What method was symfony installed, pear, svn, manually?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change some symfony function depend on deprecated function and removed functions.

To be safe, backup your symfony project, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am not able to find the change log or deprecated functions list in v1.0.22. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can't find either backup your project and try.

Comment: It shouldn't be extremely difficult.  Just make sure you are in dev.  If 1.0.11 is running, I don't think there would be a lot of issues with 1.0.22.